# Python & SQL. Inserting variable in column while in for loop

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sentiment-analysis

as part of my sentiment analysis on tweets, I need extract tweets from my database, run a python script to get the sentiment score and insert it back into the database.

Part of my code:

```
#conneting to database (works perfect)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TestTwitter;UID=;PWD=')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#Alter table (works perfect)
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD score2 varchar(255);")

#select tweet from each row and calculate score (works perfect)
cursor.execute("SELECT TestTable.Tweet FROM TestTable")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row[0])
    sentim = sentiment(row[0])
    print (sentim)

    #update table and add sentiment score for each row (not so perfect)
    cursor.execute("Update TestTable SET score2 = '" + (str(sentim)) + "';")
    cnxn.commit()
```

When updating the table, all rows get the same sentiment value as the first tweet instead of their own. The "print (sentiment)" shows the score of each tweet one by one, but it seems like the loop doesn't work when updating the table. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the while loop, but with your UPDATE command; you're telling it to update all rows in TestTable, not just the one you're working on. You need to provide a WHERE condition to that UPDATE.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TestTable.Tweet, TestTable.id FROM TestTable")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    ...
    cursor.execute("Update TestTable SET score2 = %s WHERE id = %s;", (sentim, row[1]))
```

(assuming your primary key column is called `id`).

Note also that you should get into the habit of using parameterized queries; although there's no chance of SQL injection in this code, because nothing is coming from user input, other code might have that problem so it's best to avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the update clause with a where clause that limits the rows you update to the one you want to modify.

Something like `cursor.execute("Update TestTable SET score2 = '" + (str(sentim)) + "' where Tweet = '" + row[0] + "';")`

Instead of using the `Tweet` column as key you should probably modify your select statement to extract the primary key too and use that in the where clause.

Also, using concatenation to build SQL statements can be a bad idea as it might expose you to SQL injection vulnerabilities so you might want to explore how to use prepared statements or parameters for the query.